# Why can't I gain control of 'list'

Tags: html, css, element

so, managed to sort my nav bar out the way I like it... However now I've moved onto what I want underneath it. Except I cannot appear to 'gain control' over the 'list' element... What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>St George's League - Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
    <Div class="container">
    <ul>
    <div class="nav">
        <li><img src="images/sgl-logo.jpg" height="145px" alt="SGLLogo" /></li>

    <div class="navbar">
        <li class="contact"><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li class="about"><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
        <strong><li class="leagues"><a href="leagues.html">LEAGUES</a></li></strong>
        <li class="home"><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>     
    </div><!--Navbar End-->
    </div><!--Nav End-->
    </div><!--Container End-->
    </div class="list"><strong>
        <li><a href="essex.html">Essex</a></li>
        <li><a href="london.html">London</a></li>
    </strong></div><!--Leagues End-->
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
.container {
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  font-family: arial;
  z-index: 2;
}
.navbar a {
  float: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #003399;
}
.nav li {
  display: inline;
}
.navbar {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 67px;
  padding-bottom: 45px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
}
#intro img {
  position: absolute;
  left:0px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}
.list {
position:relative;
top:300px;
}
.list a {
position:relative;
text-decoration:none;
float:left;
font-family:arial;
font-size:75px;
color:black;
}
```

Comment: I tried changing from div class to div id, changing the . and the #, no change....

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more of what it is you are trying to do?

Comment: Sure, I'm creating a couple of links that go elsewhere on the site so I can break down the site into locations... However, I cannot control the element 'list', as in I can't change position or color, size, nothing....

Comment: <li> can only be child of <ul> or <ol>, what are you trying to do actually ?

Comment: I've tried with <ul> seems to make no difference. I want to remove text decoration, change the color, set fonts and add padding... But cannot do so without obtaining control of the element. Everything I'm writing in does nothing to the element

Comment: See my answer below. I'll change it for no text decoration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
li a{
  color: #000000;
}
```

This is all you need to gain control of these in css. See the jsfiddle example here

http://jsfiddle.net/fwvc6zsc/

If you want more certainty that you are using the right one you could also change it like this:

```
strong li a{
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Still is having zero affect at my end... I've been stuck on this for over 24 hours now *loads gun

Comment: Which browser do you use? It can also be an cache issue. That it still uses the old cached css files. For chrome you can use ctrl+f5

Comment: Is at online website we can see to maybe find out what goes wrong or is it offline?

Comment: And what if you use another browser? One where you didn't go to the website you're creating.

Comment: Fixed it myself... Somehow I'd started the div with </div class="list">

Comment: Apologies for wasting your time guys

Answer (score 0):

Because you using different class

Use this:

```
.navbar li {
     css code 
}
```